# How to access ModelState.AddModelError() from IsValid function of ValidationAttribute class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate

i try to add this line `ModelState.AddModelError(string key, string errorMessage);` in `IsValid` function of `ValidationAttribute` class but fail.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public class AtleastOneAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        // For Server side
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                var oHobby=value as IEnumerable;

                foreach (var _object in oHobby)
                {
                    Hobby _oHobby = (Hobby)_object;
                    if (_oHobby.IsSelected)
                    {
                        return ValidationResult.Success;
                    }
                }

            }
             ModelState.AddModelError("Hobbies", "Err message....");

            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
```

tell me how to access `ModelState.AddModelError` from `IsValid` function of ValidationAttribute class ?

thanks

Comment: what is failing? any errors?

Comment: ModelState.AddModelError() is not accessible in isValid function. so what to do in code to access it?

Comment: You dont access `ModelState`, nor do you add a `ModelStateError` in a `ValidationAttribute`. You seem to be confused about what the attribute does. When you return a `ValidationResult`other than `Success`, the `DefaultModelBinder` adds the `ModelStateError` during the binding process (and `ModelState.IsValid` becomes `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelState` is not accessible in `IsValid` function. `IsValid` method adds an error to `ModelState` through it's return statement, so if you need to add an error just return it:

```
return new ValidationResult("Err message....");
```